# Hang during unlock, slow after that

Tags: performance

I have problems when I leave computer on during the night, when I resume it in the morning, it becomes very slow, I often wait for few minutes until login form renders, when I login, apps freeze randomly and I must restart it in order to work normally.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you check for a) high disk activity and b) memory usage? I had a similar problem a few weeks ago (which *looks like* solved itself with some updates coming in from the repos) -- you might check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158141/free-ram-disappears-memory-leak) for details and possible steps..

Comment: I checked, no memory or CPU overloads. Didn't check HDD activity, how to check that? Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way: check the LED attached and listen to the noise (grin). Without physical approximity, and to figure out who is doing all the business: Take a look at `iostat` (see also: [iostat short description and screenshots](http://www.linuxinsight.com/iostat_utility.html). If it's not installed, it ships with the `sysstat` package (so `sudo apt-get install sysstat` to get it).

Comment: It got hanging untill it render login form for 2 minutes, then it worked fine after login. Here is output of iostat https://gist.github.com/2293fe1208154b2a5cfc

Comment: And it got frozen after few minutes, so I must restart. I disabled sleep and screen locking to prevent this. BTW, after waking from sleep, hard drive LED was glowing all the time, non stop!

Comment: The glowing drive LED indicates a lot of I/O (in my case, this was either Firefox going nuts, or X running havoc -- both luckily solved itself by updates). Time to give `iotop` (package has the same name) a chance to identify the troublemaking process!

Comment: Haha, currently, it is rsync. I have some backups scheduled, and since in that backup I have huge lucene indexes, it gets messy. Will try to remove that. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you've found the cause. I made a summary and provided it as an answer, so it is easier to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution as extracted from the comments:**

Steps to find the cause involve checking...

- memory/cpu usage (e.g. using `top` to look at the processes using most of it)
- disk activity (first check the disk LED, then `iotop` from the `iotop` package proves helpful)

In most cases, one of these two steps identify the process lagging the system. Depending on what it is, further actions can be evaluated (stopping/killing that process or, as in this case, re-organize cron jobs causing heavvy activity to not have them all run at the same time in parallel).

Comment: I will accept it next week, if problem is solved, thanks ;)

Comment: You're welcome -- glad I could help!