# Evolution 3.4.3 on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, evolution

I'm currently using Evolution for my mail client on 12.04 (and no, I don't want to use Thunderbird), but the version available in the repos (3.2) has a couple of bugs (more precisely, its version of EWS has the bugs) that are fixed in later versions.

Is there a PPA available for at least 3.3? While I have no issue compiling from source, I'd rather use a PPA if it's available, but unfortunately, my own searching didn't turn up anything.

**Edit** Thanks to JXPheonix for finding a PPA. I added it and found that `apt-get upgrade` didn't want to just update Evolution and had several of the Gnome 3.4 packages held back. Installing Evolution specifically with `apt-get install evolution` worked great, though.

(Since Ubuntu was pretty adamant about *not* updating Evolution, I decided to see what I could find as to why, beyond the generic "stability reasons" that was given for everything they held back. According to [this article,](http://www.muktware.com/articles/3277/how-much-gnome-34-will-be-there-ubuntu-1204) it seems it's just because 3.4 wasn't as well-tested as 3.2 as of Precise's release.)

For those using EWS, you will need to update evolution-ews, of course. I found [this script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976894) useful for building and installing EWS. It's originally written for 3.2, but a simple change to the script to point to the correct download location (simply change the "3-2" in the Git repo clone call to "3-4") allows it to install with no problems. After updating EWS, my Exchange account is back up, complete with the global address book and Exchange calendar!

Comment: I've tried the stracciatella PPA. That would bring too much new gnome stuff. I'll wait the few days for 12.10, let's see what that brings.

Comment: BTW, Evolution 3.2 is buggy as hell. It deleted 2 IMAP folders from the server when moving them failed!

Comment: @OndraŽižka - You don't need to add all the other Gnome stuff. In fact, Ubuntu fights you if you try to just do an update. Hence the first paragraph after **Edit**.

Comment: Doesn't then Ubuntu update the other gnome stuff on periodical update check?

Comment: @OndraŽižka - **Ubuntu will not upgrade the Gnome items from the PPA.** That is why you have to explicitly tell it to install Evolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code to add the repo:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

Evolution is by the same people as gnome3, so this should contain evolution 3.4.3 (unless my information is outdated.

**EDIT**: OK, I found a PPA with evolution 3.4.2. However, it is *unofficial*, so use at your own risk.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:janvitus/gnomestracciatella`

I can't find any with 3.4.3, but this one will probably be updated at some point in the near future.

Comment: 3.2.3 is still the latest available in the repo. :(

Comment: Awesome, it works like a dream!

Comment: Just to get this clear: adding the second (gnomestracciatella) repo, doing an `apt-get update && apt-get install evolution` worked without problems and side-effects? As I also have several problems with Evolution (see [12.04 - Evolution in Precise laggy](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150860/evolution-in-precise-laggy) for example), this update might offer some solution to me as well. As I have no need for MS Exchange support, I probably could skip the EWS part?

Comment: @Izzy - I've been using it with this setup for a couple of months now and have found no major side effects. The worst issue I've come across is that it sometimes will close the expanded attachments section on a received email while in the split view (the behavior is easily corrected by clicking a different email, then going back to the one with attachments).

Comment: @Shauna Thanks a lot! So I will give this a try when I return from my vacation. With some luck, it solves the laggyness here (which I attribute mainly to the switching away from Bonobo, so I'm confident a newer version will improve this). Feel free to recommend this on the linked question and grab the bounty for it before it expires. Would be a shame, as my question there has no answer yet...

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code from the internet and then compile and run it.

> http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/download.shtml

Comment: As I said in my question, I would prefer to use a PPA if available. I am already aware that the source code is available.