# How to update Evolution Mail Client in xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, evolution

I'm using xubuntu 12.04, and i need to upgrade Evolution Mail Client from 3.2.3 to the latest version. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are these terminal commands safe for installing Evolution 3.8.0?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280344/are-these-terminal-commands-safe-for-installing-evolution-3-8-0) or http://askubuntu.com/questions/167475/evolution-3-4-3-on-12-04

Comment: I don't think the question should be close. since the other questions don't really answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will install Evolution 3.6.4.  To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:support-bec/evolution
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

Once done you will get:

[image]

Comment: Can i install it on top of the old version? Or i need first to uninstall the old version? Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but **with no data**.  I have to say, just to be safe, backup your data, and then restore on 3.6.4, if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Ukh it gives this when i try to update: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/support-bec/evolution/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found !!

Comment: I got the same error, but it installed OK.

Comment: Seems this PPA only has packages for 12.10 and 13.10 now, which is what's causing the 404 errors. Anyone know of any alternatives?

Comment: @AaronB.Russell - find anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not -- even tried compiling the newer packages from source, but it had dependencies on newer parts of GTK which in turn had other dependencies and basically it wasn't plausible to continue without recompiling huge amounts of the system. Ubuntu 14.04 came out since then which was an LTS release so we ended up just upgrading.