# How to completely remove evolution including configuration?

Tags: gnome, package-management, email, evolution

I want to remove all of evolution since it's missed up (takes an eternity to load mails, probably need to clean up my gigant gmailbox).

So, I've done `sudo apt-get purge evolution` , removed my google account in my settings and then the config folders in `$HOME` as listed [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.10/data-storage.html.en)

But even then after reinstalling evolution it still loads my email accounts as if nothing was erased.

What did I overlook?

Answer (score 0):

Also, did you clean out your gmail acct, If you didn't Evolution is doing what its suposed to retreiving ALL of you mail.

As an aside, I find that the -purge option doesn't always remove everything. I occassionslly find that I need to manually remove some of the data cache files.
To do so, type in the terminal 'find , as this in some, very few, cases finds cruft that wasn't removed as apt-get  again only in some cases believes thatvypu still want to keep that data for later use.

Comment: I cleaned out my gmail (that is to say: archived everything before this year, probably i later need to set up evolution only to subscribe to my inbox). 
Could you explain what command i exactly need to give in terminal? I tried 'find evolution' but could not find antyting. thx

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179340/how-to-reset-evolution-settings-to-defaults) topic. After executing the gconf commands, it still showed up my other online accounts as entered in system settings. After this i removed all of the home folders and evolution finally showed up the account-wizard.

Comment: Now I understand: the other online accounts (yahoo, hotmail) were configured with evolution data server to retrieve my mails. Hence the configuration wizard did not pop up. My mistake!