# Email-client such as Evolution with Sent-emails -folder? 

Tags: evolution, email

I zwitched on Desktop from Mutt to Evolution to some extent. Now I cannot find my sent emails so where are the sent -emails when they are sent with Evolution -email-program?

Comment: ...perhaps related problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186283/how-can-i-change-wastebasket-folder-to-trash-folder-in-evolution), about Wastebasket -misconfiguration. I cannot find its setting in Evolution so I cannot easily manage trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on multiple issues. The word `Evolution` is a bit red-herring, the same politics works over different devices -- more [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29065/email-client-with-sent-emails-from-many-emails-under-imap) with Android -- of course the UI is different with Evolution, go to `Edit > Preferences > Sending Email > Defaults > Sent`.

**IMAP or POP3?**

> If you use IMAP and multiple devices, please, note that your settings must correspond to each other over every email-client -- more [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29065/email-client-with-sent-emails-from-many-emails-under-imap). If you use some Online-email-client, you must make sure its settinsg are correct -- for example, Gmail Labels set to invisible makes also your Evolution Sent emails invisible. If your server-side email-client such as mutt has a wrong `record` -field, it means every IMAP email-client will malfunction. If your Gmail filters has some odd `Delete It`, it may delete all of your sent -emails -- also a possible reason why IMAP -mailbox may not work.
>
> Now POP3 is much simpler. It just directs every email to different mailboxes, meaning you need to replicate your work over multiple devices -- driving you mad if you have many email-clients like me: mutt in Server, Evolution in Desktop, K9 in Android, iOS email in iPad etc. But the good side is that the settings between different email-clients won't intercept one another the way they do with IMAP -configured mailboxes.

**Perhaps useful**

> 1. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29065/email-client-with-sent-emails-from-many-emails-under-imap
> 2. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63537/how-can-i-specify-the-sent-folder-for-gmail-on-ipad